# Find the minimum subset of linear equations that derives a given linear equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, discrete-optimization, algebraic-independence

Given variables $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ and a set of (linear) equations between them, how do I find the minimum subset of these equations that derive a given (valid) equation.

Example:
Given $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{10}$, and these 4 equations:

$$1. \ a_1 - a_2 = a_3 - a_4$$

$$2. \ a_3 - a_4 = a_5 - a_6$$

$$3. \ a_5 - a_6 = a_1 - a_7$$

$$4. \ a_8 - a_9 = a_{8} - a_{10}$$

Given the valid equation $a_2 = a_7$, the minimum subset of equations that derive this is  $\{1, 2, 3\}$.

Given the valid equation $a_1 - a_5 = a_2 - a_6$, the minimum set is $\{1, 2\}$.

Given the valid equation $a_9 = a_{10}$, the answer is $\{4\}$

This question arises in an engineering problem I'm working on, the set of linear equations are always in the form of either **(1)** $v_a - v_b = v_c - v_d$ where $a, b, c, d$ are not necessarily different, or **(2)** $v_a - v_b = 1$, and the target equation is always either $v_p = v_q$ or $v_x - v_y = v_m - v_n$.

I figured if there is a principle that solves this, then it should work the same for general linear equations as well, hence the generality of the question.

Of course there is the option of brute-forcing through all the subsets but I got a feeling that there should be some clever linear algebra procedure or matrix decomposition that derives this subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For linear equations with only integer coefficients, you can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Rewrite the equations as $\sum_j c_{ij} a_j = d_i$, where $c_{ij}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $d_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, and rewrite the target equation as $\sum_j b_j a_j = 0$, where $b_j\in\mathbb{Z}$.  For equation $i$, introduce nonnegative integer decision variables $x_i$ and $y_i$ to indicate whether to multiply equation $i$ by a positive or negative integer, respectively.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_i (x_i+y_i)$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_i c_{ij}(x_i-y_i) &= b_j &&\text{for all $j$}\\
\sum_i d_i(x_i-y_i) &= 0
\end{align}

Comment: In the case of $a_1 - a_2 = a_2 - a_3$, we are having the situation of $a_1 - 2a_2 + a_3 = 0$, so the coefficient here is $2$ for $a_2$. Is there anyway around this? P/S: I also edited the original question where besides the form $v_a - v_b = v_c - v_d$, there is also $v_a - v_b = 1$.

Comment: As long as adding or subtracting the selected equations is sufficient, the formulation I provided works.  More generally, if you can multiply each equation by an integer (instead of just by $0$, $1$, or $-1$), treat $x_i$ and $y_i$ as nonnegative integer variables instead of binary variables.

Comment: Thank you, just to clarify, what you are saying is to minimize $|x|_1$, such that $C^Tx = b$ where $C$ is the matrix with entries $c_ij$, $x$ is the variable to optimize, and $b$ is the target vector $b_j$.

Comment: Yes, but you also need $d^T x = 0$ to get the correct RHS for the target equality.

Comment: Any particular reason why the coefficients have to be integer? There are standard techniques to linear program with real valued coefficients (e.g. scipy.optimize.linprog() doesn't say anything about integers), and there isn't any reason failing real coefficients to solve the problem as far as I can think of.

Comment: No, this formulation does not depend on integer constraint coefficients.  But do you want the decision variables to be integers?

Comment: I don't think I need them to be integers. If they are zero, then I'm not using the corresponding equations, if they are non-zero (positive), then I'm using them. Whether the decision is -1, 1, or 0.5 or 2.0 doesn't matter.

Comment: OK, then LP will suffice. One caveat here is that we have strayed from the original problem of minimizing the *number* of equations used to now minimizing the sum of magnitudes.  These two objectives are correlated but will not always yield the same subset of equations.